# Don't get expected data with fetch/async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

Coming from Jquery $.get, I am trying to rewrite a function that gets data in a json. So far, this is what I do:

```
async function get_highlights(){
  const mirespuesta = await fetch("/api/v1/gethighlights/"+network_number)
  .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
      }
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
      console.log(json) // --> here, I get the correct dara
      return json;
  })
  .catch(function () {
      this.dataError = true;
  })
  return mirespuesta
} // but I don't get that data returned
```

But I just get this when I call the fuction:

[image]

that has the values, but I can't get them returned or used on the main scope of my application.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't mix `await` with `.then()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what your function should look like:

```js
async function get_highlights() {
  const mirespuesta = await fetch("/api/v1/gethighlights/"+network_number);
  if (!mirespuesta.ok) {
      throw new Error("HTTP error " + mirespuesta.status);
  }
  return mirespuesta.json(); 
}
```

But, **most importantly** this is how it should be used:

```js
const mydata = await get_highlights();
```

An `async` function **ALWAYS** returns a promise, and your question probably becomes a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It gives me an error in the important part: ''await' is only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules'

Comment: @JuanseCora that’s because the function where you call get_highlights needs to be async

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you never *return* the promise chain from your function. So your `async` function's return value is a promise fulfilled with `undefined`, just like a non-`async` function with no `return` returns `undefined`.

There's another issue with that code: If you're using an `async` function, generally it's best to use `await` rather than `.then`, `.catch`, etc. Also, don't catch rejection in the function; instead, let the caller handle it so it knows something went wrong.

So for instance:

```
async function get_highlights() {
    const response = await fetch("/api/v1/gethighlights/"+network_number);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

But if you really want to handle errors inline:

```
async function get_highlights() {
    const response = await fetch("/api/v1/gethighlights/"+network_number);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    try {
        return await response.json();
    } catch { // Note: ES2019 allows optional `catch` bindings 
        this.dataError = true;
    }
}
```

but again I **don't recommend that**, because the caller has to check to see whether they got data or `undefined` when the promise is fulfilled (or check `dataError`, I guess :-) ).

Side note: Note that in the first example, which doesn't have a `try`/`catch`, I did `return response.json();` but in the second example, where the `return` is inside a `try`/`catch`, I did `return await respohnse.json();`. The reason is that when returning a promise **at the top level** of the function, there's no effective difference between `return somePromise` and `return await somePromise`, but that's **not true** if the code is in a control block like a `try`/`catch`. Having the `await` ensures that our `catch` block is executed if the promise is rejected. Not having it wouldn't ensure that.

Comment: Thank you very much for that super detailed answer! I feel like I have really learnt important stuff that I was missing :) The side note is amazing. Literally saved for further reference.

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm imagining the special kitchen cabinet where all the SO coffee mugs are stored

Comment: @Pointy - Sadly, they stop sending them after the first couple. :-( I have a grand total of three, and one of them I had to sort of shame them into sending.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use just `await` twice

```
try {
  const mirespuesta = await (await fetch("/api/v1/gethighlights/"+network_number)).json();
} catch {
  throw new Error(response.status);
}
return mirespuesta;
```